# AngularJS force validation or wait for $scope.myForm.$valid to refresh

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I update the `$scope` in my Javascript and I would like to know if the form is now valid or not. How can I force validation to occur or wait for Angular to run the validation?

This is some sample code. When I click the button, `$scope.validateA = true` makes the form invalid, but not straight away. So on the next line of code, if I look at `$scope.abForm.$valid`, it is still `true`.

```
var validationApp = angular.module('validationApp', []);

validationApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.submitA = function() {
    $scope.validateA = true;
    //force validation to run here??
    alert($scope.abForm.$valid);
  };
});


<div ng-app="validationApp" ng-controller="mainController">
    <form name="abForm">
      a
      <input ng-required='validateA' ng-model='a'>
      <button type="button" ng-click="submitA()">submit a</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

[See the sample in Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/s8FGkXRSy383kTVWQNyq)

Comment: Is there a reason you want to change the required attribute on the fly?  If you set the `ng-required` directive to `true` outright it works fine. http://plnkr.co/edit/ykjALPsvT6z2C0o6SrzV?p=preview

Comment: @m.e.conroy My actual scenario is I have a 'submit' button that runs the full set of validations, and a 'save' button that only runs a smaller set of validations, so the user can save their work in progress.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right in that Angular hasn't `$digest`ed the changes in the form yet in order to set the form's valid/invalid properties.

You need to wait for the next `$digest` cycle.  You can't force it but you can wait for it, if you use `$timeout` without a wait time you can force your alert statement to wait for the next `$digest` cycle where any inputs for the form will have been verified.

http://plnkr.co/edit/mjPuDPhS8bnbN15lO7yF?p=preview

I added this to your plunker:

```
validationApp.controller('mainController',function($scope,$timeout){
    $scope.submitA = function(){
        $scope.validateA = true
        $timeout(function(){
            alert($scope.abForm.$valid);
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: Its not the ideal solution, but I also think that setting a form element as required at the time of submission is not ideal either.  What you're doing is changing the way the form operates during the submission phase.

Comment: Thanks. Before I posted the question, I was starting to think this way of turning field validation on/off might be going against the grain of Angular. But since the solution is as simple as passing a callback to $timeout, I think this validation code works just fine after all.